# Modular form, number of divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

The Fourier expansion of Eisenstein series $E_k$ $(k \ge 4)$, which are modular forms, as well as the quasimodular $E_2$, involves powers-of-divisors $\sigma_{k-1}(n) = \sum_{d|n} d^{k-1}$.

Is there some generalization of a modular form (quasimodular, mock modular, etc.) where you can find some similar Fourier expansion of the form $$f(z) = 1 + C \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sigma_0(n) q^n, \; q = e^{2\pi i z}$$ involving just the number-of-divisors function $\sigma_0(n)$? I haven't been able to find this.

Comment: Do you know of examples of generalized modular forms involving *any* $\sigma_{k-1}$ where $k - 1$ is even?

Comment: This question was asked before, and I answered it here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128533/q-series-related-to-dn-of-divisors-of-n

Comment: @GHfromMO: Why don't you want the question to be closed as duplicate then(?) -- At least so far you didn't cast a close vote.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Done.